# Problem with proving that graph consisting of $n$ edges and $n$ vertices has only one circuit.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Is this true that graph consisting of $n$ edges and $n$ vertices has only one circuit.

I drew some graphs on paper and I believe that it is true. But how to prove that? I will be glad for any help.

Comment: Not unless you require *connected* graphs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The disjoint union of two triangles is a counterexample.

If you require connected graphs, I believe the statement is true. You should proceed by induction:

It shouldn't be too hard to show by induction on the number of vertices that any such graph is a circuit with some number of trees affixed to it such that the trees have no vertices in common and each tree only has one vertex in common with the circuit.

Comment: Okay, it took me five corrections but I finally think I'm satisfied with my response. If someone can find a counterexample please inform me. I'm doing my honors thesis in graph theory and I should really be more certain of this than I am...

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, the statement is only true about connected graphs.  Here's a quick way to prove it in this case.  A connected graph on $n$ vertices has $n-1$ edges iff it is a tree.  Trees have no cycles, so adding one more edge creates exactly one cycle.  (To show this, you can use the fact that for any distinct vertices $u,v$ there is a unique $u,v$-path in a tree.)

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by Nick's answer, try proving:

- a connected graph with $n$ vertices and $n - 1$ edges is a tree (because any such graph has average degree less than $2$, so a vertex of degree $1$, delete this vertex and use induction),
- a tree has exactly one non-backtracking path between any two vertices,
- so a graph with $n$ vertices and $n$ edges is a tree with one edge added, every cycle must use this edge and another path between its ends, but there is only one such thing.